# Microchip MPLAB IDE and XC8 compiler build options

Tags: c, makefile, flags, microchip, xc8

I try to build a C project with the XC8 compiler (V 2.32).
I get some errors from the compiler. I already added "--chip=$(MP_PROCESSOR_OPTION)" to the "Makefile-default.mk" file.

Here is the build log:

```
make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/media/diskhome2/files/MPLABXProjects-backup-2021-03-26/led-pov-8/led-pov-8.X'
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/default/production/led-pov-8.X.production.hex
make[2]: Entering directory '/media/diskhome2/files/MPLABXProjects-backup-2021-03-26/led-pov-8/led-pov-8.X'
"/media/diskhome2/files/microchip/xc8/v2.32/pic/bin/xc8"  -mcpu=16F628A --chip=16F628A -c    -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default  -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file  -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall   -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto     -o build/default/production/my-pov.p1 my-pov.c 
/media/diskhome2/files/microchip/xc8/v2.32/pic/bin/picc -mcpu=16F628A --chip=16F628A -c -fno-short-double -fno-short-float -O0 -fasmfile -maddrqual=ignore -xassembler-with-cpp -mwarn=-3 -Wa,-a -DXPRJ_default=default -msummary=-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file -ginhx032 -Wl,--data-init -mno-keep-startup -mno-osccal -mno-resetbits -mno-save-resetbits -mno-download -mno-stackcall -std=c99 -gdwarf-3 -mstack=compiled:auto:auto -o build/default/production/my-pov.p1 my-pov.c
(925) extraneous argument to "-S" option
make[2]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:110: build/default/production/my-pov.p1] Error 1
make[1]: *** [nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:91: .build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: .build-impl] Error 2
(908) exit status = 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/diskhome2/files/MPLABXProjects-backup-2021-03-26/led-pov-8/led-pov-8.X'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/diskhome2/files/MPLABXProjects-backup-2021-03-26/led-pov-8/led-pov-8.X'

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 256ms)
```

How can I build the program? I can't find the "-S" in the log.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.I did reinstall the XC8 compiler toolchain. After that I did select the toolchain in the MPLAB IDE: "Tools->Options->Embedded".
Select "Add" and Select the XC8 toolchain "bin" directory.
Select "Apply". Now the XC8 toolchain should be ready!

Answer (score 0):

I got this type of error "Configuration "default" builds with "XC8", but no toolchains of that type are installed. "

I cleared by installing compiler XC8 and "Tools->Options->Embedded->Build Tools" in that mention the  path of compiler file and click ok.